# Rails: Flash Messages not appearing anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications

So let's say I have code like this:

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base 
  # Add before_filter here and devise should handle the redirection if the user is not signed in.
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:vote_up]

  def vote_up
  begin
  current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:error] =  "You have already voted"
  end
 end

end
```

Neither of the messages "You have voted successfully" or "You have already voted" are being shown.

In my view I have:

```
enter code here

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <%= @post.embed .html_safe %>
    <header>
        <h7><%= @post.name %></h7>
    </header>
<h8><%= @post.title %></h8>
<article>
<%= @post.content .html_safe %>

<p>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %> |
<%= link_to('Vote for this song!', vote_up_post_path(@post), :method => :post) %></p>

<p><id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

No dice. I'm still not getting flash messages anywhere. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `flash` before `redirect_to`

And in your view

```
<p>
  <%= flash[:success] unless flash[:success].blank? %>
  <%= flash[:error] unless flash[:error].blank? %>
</p>
```

You can check this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) as well

Comment: Looks like you answered first and most thoroughly.  It worked! That was almost the very last hurdle! Thank you.

Comment: But then, why is `redirect_to @user, notice: "Success"` working and not `redirect_to @user, success: "Success"` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have used

```
flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
```

in your controller and you have called

```
<%= notice %>
```

in your views. You have to change either in your controller or in your views.

You can add

format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'You have voted successfully.' }

in your controller and you will get the message that you require.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well there are about 20 million ways to do it... What's the advantage of putting it in a div? What makes this one the best?

Comment: Well no probs if you don't keep it in a div.It will work either ways.

Comment: Then why say the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is like: `<p><id="notice"><%= notice %></p>`

You need `<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>`